# Mariadb is not truncating even Innodb Undo log Truncate is On

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, logs

we have configured the below settings in our configuration file.

```
 --innodb_file_per_table=1
 --innodb_undo_tablespaces=3
 --innodb_undo_directory=/var/lib/mysql/
 --innodb_undo_log_truncate=ON
 --innodb_max_undo_log_size=10737418240
```

However, the size of undo log files have reached more than 15GB and they are not truncating as per the set size of 10GB.

Any advise, what needs to be changed or add will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like [MDEV-32050](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32050) which has been fixes (per affected versions on the bug report). If this is not the case for you, create a new bug report with a disclosed MariaDB version.